# Google Tag Manager not firing the tag when the Data Layer variable is being pushed

Tags: tags, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

in my website there is a form that allows the users to submit their email. When the user clicks submit, the email is pushed to the Data Layer. I have tested this by checking the data layer values using console:

email: "abc@gmail.com"

I have also set a Google Tag Manager variable called email, and I have created a trigger as shown below:
[image]

Now I set my tag to fire when this trigger is true. But my tag does not fire. I don't understand why. Can someone please explain why this may not be working?

Comment: Is this again due to the fact that your site is a single page app, as per a previous post?

Comment: yes exactly, that's why @nyuen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not working because my website is a single page app and that's why Custom Event Triggers need to be replaced by History Change Triggers

Comment: This doesn't work because your trigger is incorrect. You should create dataLayer variable and use it in your trigger with a click, but not as a name of a custom event.

Comment: @mrbubu, it works when I use a History Change Trigger and use dataLayer variables